# .net 6 azure function time trigger 404 not found error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

First time with .NET 6 runtime on Azure and I get the following error.

[image]

The time trigger function is not fired and I can not run it manually from portal.

Also, I try the following documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http
but i get 404 not found error again.

*Time trigger working from localhost

*Visual Studio 2022 v 17.2.3

- "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time I create Time Trigger Azure function for NCRONTAB expression I use the following site https://crontab.guru/every-minute

In this case (once every 4 hours) is not working. So the 404 error not found based on an incorrect expression.

The valid expression is "0 0 */4 * * *" and i was using "0 */4 * * *"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: that resolved my issue. not sure what happened, but my `TimerTrigger` functions stopped working with a 404 on a personal project. I'm not sure at which point, but they were working for sure. My bet is that from .NET 5 or 6, the only accepted CRON is 6 digits (including seconds)